# Add a custom style to victory chart bar

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

I want to create a custom bar chart with Victory like this:

[image]

How can I add a horizontal line in the graph every 10%?

This is my sample code:

```
const data = [
  { day: 1, data: 0 },
  { day: 2, data: 1 },
  { day: 3, data: 2 },
  { day: 4, data: 2 },
  { day: 5, data: 0 },
];

const BarChart = () => {
  return (
    <VictoryChart domainPadding={20} theme={VictoryTheme.material}>
      <VictoryAxis
        tickFormat={(x) => `${x.toFixed(0)}`}
        style={{
          grid: { stroke: "none" },
          ticks: { size: 0 },
        }}
      />
      <VictoryAxis
        dependentAxis
        tickFormat={(x) => `${x}`}
        style={{
          grid: { stroke: "none" },
          ticks: { size: 0 },
        }}
      />
      <VictoryStack>
        <VictoryBar data={data} style={{ data: { fill: '#379F4B' } }} x="day" y="data" />
      </VictoryStack>
    </VictoryChart>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `tickValues`? Example:

```
<VictoryAxis dependentAxis
  tickValues={[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}
  ...other stuff...
/>
```

Comment: the problem is not the tick but line in the bar...please see edited image.